# Syntax error in MySql using subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Below is MySql query:

```
$queryfilter = "SELECT * FROM tablename where sector = " .$_SESSION['idfilterdrop']. " AND 
region IN (SELECT region from 
    tablename where sector = " . $_SESSION['sector'] ." OR region = " . 
 $_SESSION['r1'] ." OR theme = " . $_SESSION['theme'] .")";
```

Help me to find the syntax error. I am sure there is a problem of double quotes in the above query. When I run this query on MySql prompt it runs fine but when I replace the constant value with variables this query doesn't work.

Comment: It would help a lot to see the actual error you are getting.

Comment: Use [tag:pdo] instead?

Comment: Can I have table name as database ?

Comment: It gives me two errors. First when I check if the query is correct "if(!$queryfilter) echo "Filter query not found". The code echos this line and also When I pass the value of $queryfilter to mysql_num_rows () as "mysql_num_rows($queryfilter) it gives me an error "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean "

Comment: Hi Vivek, I gave the table name as "database" as it's a forum and I have to give a dummy name. I know that with the select statement I have to give table name and not the database name.

Comment: What are the type (or values) of the sessions? (strings, numbers, arrays)

Comment: session variable stores stores strings

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't know if your `$_SESSION` array contains integers or strings. if the elements `sector`, `r1` or `theme` are strings, you need to quote them in your SQL, like this: `WHERE sector = '". $_SESSION['sector'] . "' OR`.

Also, your table being named `database` does not help. If I recall correctly, `DATABASE` is a reserved word, so you'll need to put backtics around that table name:

```
... FROM `database` ...
```